# Couchdb views generation

Tags: couchdb, couchdb-futon

I am learning couchdb, so I have a very basic questions. Suppose I have a couch database called `email` where documents look like:

```
{
  "_id": "fe7759fdf36t",
  "status": "sent",
  "sent_at": 1357151443,
}

{
  "_id": "ewrwe4a38d2353",
  "status": "failed",
  "sent_at": 2347151421,
}

{
  "_id": "f4559fjffd2353",
  "status": "sent",
  "sent_at": 11715154,
}
```

I want to create two views

1) Retrieve all documents where `status = sent`
2) Retrieve all documents where `status = failed and sent_at > 11715157`
3) Retrieve all documents sorted by `sent_at` descending/ascending and `status = sent`

For (1), I wrote,

```
{
    "_id": "_design/sentdoc",
    "_rev": "2-dd88de7196c06eed41d2d83a958f0388",
    "views": {
        "query": {
            "map": "function(doc) { if(doc.status == 'sent') {emit(doc_id, doc);} }"
        }
    }
}
```

I guess I am doing something wrong there, so it is not working. Can anyone suggest how to write all these three views?

Comment: How do you know it doesn't work?

Answer (score 1):

Create a view like this

```
function(doc){
  emit([doc.status, doc.sent_at], doc); 
}
```

**Query #1**

Try these params in your curl statement (or Ruby library or whatever)

```
startkey = ["sent"]
endkey = ["sent",{}]
```

**Query #2**

```
startkey = ["failed", 11715157]
endkey = ["failed", {}]
```

**Query #3**

```
startkey = ["sent"]
endkey = ["sent", {}]
descending = true
```

I've not tested this, but should point you in the right direction.

Comment: Good answer, I edited Query #3 to fix an issue with the endkey. To make the examples clear, the actual requests to the view should look something like: http://localhost:5984/database/_design/sentdoc/_view/query?startkey=%5B%22failed%22%5D&endkey=%5B%22failed%22,%7B%7D%5D